# Why the Sobolev norm is equivalent with the graph norm of the fractional Laplacian operator?

Tags: fractional-sobolev-spaces

Why the Sobolev norm $\left\|u\right\|_{H^s}=\left\|(1+\xi^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u}\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ is equivalent to the graph norm of the operator $(-\Delta)^{s/2}$,
$$\left\|u\right\|_{(-\Delta)^{s/2}}:=\left\|u\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}+\left\|(-\Delta)^{s/2}u\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$$ with $(-\Delta)^{s/2}u=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(|\xi|^{s}\widehat{u}\right)$ ?

My attempt: I think that this is right because $(1+|\xi|^2)^{s}\leq C(s) (1+(|\xi|^2)^s)$ and $(1+(|\xi|^2)^s)\leq (1+|\xi|^2)^s$ (for all $s\geq 0$) or not?

Comment: You actually got the point. You just to prove the two inequalities at the end of your post. :))

Comment: Yes, but, I remember seeing that 0<s<1 (or 0<s<2) something like that. The equivalence of the norms of  is valid for all s>0? (this is my doubt)

Comment: It is actually still equivalent.

Comment: for all $s\geq 0$, right? I ask because I can't find any book or reference where this fact seems so simple...

Comment: Yes, but probably the proof is easier assuming $|\xi|\geqslant 1$ or something similar.